# Returning COM object to JScript

Tags: c++, activex, javascript

I am trying to pass a COM object from an ActiveX component to JScript. So far I have tried the following method of doing so:

```
STDMETHODIMP CHSNetwork::CreateIPPPacket(VARIANT ** ppv)
{
    IIPPacket *iipp;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_IPPacket, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IIPPacket, (void **)&iipp);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr) && ppv)
    {
        CComVariant cvar((IUnknown *)iipp);
        hr = cvar.Detach(*ppv);
    }

    return hr;
}
```

The following JScript causes the error `Variable uses an Automation type not supported in JScript`:

```
var hsn = new ActiveXObject("ZIENetwork.HSNetwork");
var ipp = hsn.CreateIPPPacket();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah. I got it. I needed to pass a `VARIANT *` not a `VARIANT **`. I guess I still get confused by pointers-to-pointers as it relates to return values with COM.

Thus the correct code is:

```
STDMETHODIMP CHSNetwork::CreateIPPPacket(VARIANT * ppv)
{
    // TODO: Add your implementation code here
    IIPPacket *iipp;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_IPPacket, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IIPPacket, (void **)&iipp);
    if(ppv)
    {
        CComVariant cvar((IUnknown *)iipp);
        hr = cvar.Detach(ppv);
    }

    return hr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course if you only ever pass back an interface you can pass back a IDispatch** or IUnknown**, you don't need the VARIANT, just a thought :)